# WTForm not displayed, got python code instead

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I’m making a form for flask using WTForms. Here is the corresponding code :

```
class UploadForm(flask.ext.wtf.Form):
    def __init__(self,year):
        flask.ext.wtf.Form.__init__(self)
        self.year=year
        subjects = app.config["SUBJECTS"][year]
        self.fichier = wtforms.fields.FileField(u'Fichier')
        self.subject = wtforms.fields.SelectField(u'Matière', choices=subjects)
        self.submit = wtforms.fields.SubmitField(u'Envoyer')

@app.route('/upload/<year>')
def upload(year):
    print year
    form = UploadForm(year)
    return flask.render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```

And here is the template `upload.html` :

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h2>Upload</h2>
  <form action="{{ url_for('get', year='1A') }}" method="post"
          enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

    {{ form.fichier.label }}
    {{ form.fichier }}

    {{ form.subject.label }}
    {{ form.subject }}

    {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

But when I run it, the form isn’t displayed, and instead I have this :

```
<UnboundField(FileField, (u'Fichier',), {})> <UnboundField(SelectField, (u'Mati\xe8re',), {'choices': [('MA111', 'MA111'), ('NE111', 'NE111')]})>  <UnboundField(SubmitField, (u'Envoyer',), {})>
```

Can someone help me to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fields of the form need to be defined as class variables:

```
class UploadForm(flask.ext.wtf.Form):
    fichier = wtforms.fields.FileField(u'Fichier')
    subject = wtforms.fields.SelectField(u'Matière')
    submit = wtforms.fields.SubmitField(u'Envoyer')

    def __init__(self, year):
        flask.ext.wtf.Form.__init__(self)
        self.year=year
        self.subject.choices = app.config["SUBJECTS"][year]
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you are creating the form without any fields and then adding unbound fields behind its back in your `UploadForm.__init__` method.  The `wtforms.form.Form` class actually does a lot of metaclass magic behind the scenes.  The way to do what you are doing is as follows:

```
from flask import render_template
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import FileField, SelectField, SubmitField

class UploadForm(Form):
    """This seemingly static class will be transformed
    by the WTForms metaclass constructor"""

    fichier = FileField(u'Fichier')
    subject = SelectField(u'Matière')
    submit = SubmitField(u'Envoyer')


@app.route('/upload/<year>')
def upload(year):
    subjects = app.config['SUBJECTS'][year]

    form = UploadForm()
    # We can set the choices dynamically, based on year
    form.subject.choices = subjects

    return render_template('upload.html', form=form)
```